# react+redux componentdidmount() is called repeatedly

Tags: jquery, reactjs, redux, jquery-events

I build a `react+redux` project, and get `xx.html`, `xx.js` static files.
then I use `jQuert.load()` to load these static file , but i found that `componentdidmount()`  was called repeatedly.

I loaded `readux data` in `componentdidmount`, so the result is that open the same page repeatedly, the page will run `$.load(xx.html)` everytime, and send Superimposed network request.

Five times request:

[image]

Comment: in my component define:
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.initData()
    }
in my webpage, I load the react page like this:
    $("#main").load(htmlUrl, callback);

Comment: add checkpoint so that it will not from second time

Comment: Thanks,Would you pelease write detailly

Answer (score 1):

Why not try putting the call in componentWillMount? Repeated calls might be caused by redux data changing the component making it rerender and make a call again

Comment: thanks~~~I had tried that. I found that componentDidMount() was called repeatedly. It is not redux data changing trigger